# Tried fetching the highest row...sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have the below query -

```
 select w1.System_Id, w1.TeamProjectSK, w1.System_State, w1.System_Rev 
 from dbo.DimWorkItem w1
  where w1.System_Id = 29259
  order by w1.TeamProjectSK asc, w1.System_Rev desc
```

The output looks like -

```
System_Id    TeamProjectSK  System_State    System_Rev
29259    4            Closed              6
29259    4            Resolved            5
29259    4            Active              4
29259    4            Active              3
29259    4            Active              2
29259    4            Proposed            1
```

Now, i need my output to look like -

```
System_Id    TeamProjectSK  System_State    System_Rev
29259    4            Closed              6
29259    4            Resolved            5
29259    4            Active              4
29259    4            Proposed            1
```

That is, I want to have the highest value in the "System_Rev" column grouped by "System_State". I tried the below query -

```
 select w1.System_Id, w1.TeamProjectSK, w1.System_State, w1.System_Rev 
 from dbo.DimWorkItem w1
 inner join 
 (
    select System_State, max(System_Rev) as m 
    from dbo.DimWorkItem group by System_State
 ) w
 on w1.System_State = w.System_State and w1.System_Rev = w.m
 order by w1.System_Id asc, w1.TeamProjectSK asc
```

But it didn't work to my benefit. Please help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest this:

```
 select w1.System_Id, w1.TeamProjectSK, w1.System_State, 
   max(w1.System_Rev) as System_Rev 
 from dbo.DimWorkItem w1
      where w1.System_Id = 29259
    group by w1.System_Id, w1.TeamProjectSK, w1.System_State
    having max(w1.System_Rev)>0
      order by w1.TeamProjectSK asc, System_Rev desc
```

I tried an example with the same scenario. A group by and a having will help.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_X(FIELD1 VARCHAR (100), FIELD2 INTEGER);

INSERT INTO TEST_X VALUES 
('s1','100'),('S2','1000'),('S2','220'),('S3','20');


SELECT FIELD1, MAX(FIELD2) FROM TEST_X 
GROUP BY FIELD1 
HAVING MAX(FIELD2)>1
```

I have it here.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5b02/3

Who said this doesnt work? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53c5e/7

Comment: @Rajaganesh I didn't downvote, but your previous solution wasn't working at first and the example was about a different table and situation that the one explained on the question

Answer (score 8):

Since you are using SQL Server you can use `row_number()`, if you have sql server 2005+:

```
select System_Id, TeamProjectSK, System_State, System_Rev
from
(
    select w1.System_Id, w1.TeamProjectSK, w1.System_State, 
      w1.System_Rev, row_number() over (
        partition by w1.System_Id, w1.TeamProjectSK, w1.System_State 
        order by w1.System_Rev desc) rn
    from dbo.DimWorkItem w1
    where w1.System_Id = 29259
) d
where rn = 1
order by System_Id, TeamProjectSK desc;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53c5e/2).

If you want to use the `max()` aggregate functions, then you can use a subquery:

```
select d1.system_id, 
  d1.teamprojectsk, 
  d1.system_state,
  d1.system_rev
from DimWorkItem d1
inner join
(
  select max(system_rev) system_rev,
    system_id, 
    teamprojectsk,
    system_state
  from DimWorkItem
  group by system_id, teamprojectsk, system_state
) d2
  on d1.system_id = d2.system_id
  and d1.teamprojectsk = d2.teamprojectsk
  and d1.system_state = d2.system_state
  and d1.system_rev = d2.system_rev
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53c5e/3)

Comment: *sigh* I was about to post this answer, but alas, you were faster. +1, though I would say that this is valid for SQL Server 2005+

Comment: Thanks...it helped was really fast.

Comment: @Rajaganesh Your query as written initially failed to run, my comment was valid.  Your downvote to my answer is vengeful.

Comment: @Rajaganesh code that works is still code that works, and code that doesn't is, well, wrong. And down-voting someone for pointing it out, and making assumptions about who must have down-voted you so you need to pay them back, is absolutely wrong.

Comment: @Rajaganesh Your edited answer does work, but when I initially posted my comment, your code was failing and would not run. I am not going to argue with you but you are making a large assumption that I downvoted your answer based on my comment.